# Program does not print the values of the variables

Tags: bash

So here is my code

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

echo -n "Please enter the first integer: "
read $num1
echo -n "Please enter the second integer: "
read $num2

if [[ "$num1" -eq "$num2" ]];
then
    echo "$num1  is -eq $num2"
fi
```

The issue with this program is that it doesn't print `$num1` and `$num2` values after statement is true

By the way, Is there any way to handle integer inputs and comparisons better?

Comment: Use `read num1` instead of `read $num1`. (shell is not perl)

Comment: You will get an error message if the input is not numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bodo says, your `read` statements are wrong.

If you have a command `read $num1` then the shell will look up the value of num1 (let us say it is "fred" and then run `read fred` to get a line of input and store it in the variable fred.

If, as is probably the case, there is no current value for num1, then the shell will run `read`, and this will store the value in the variable `REPLY`.

In general you should **always** quote your variables. If you did and had said `read "$num1"`, then you would have an error message when the shell turned this into `read ""` saying that the empty string wasn't a valid name of a variable.